# Can I move a local Asset to S3 and keep relations?

Tags: assets, s3

I have a Assets folder (local) with 100 assets in it.

Now I have a new Assets folder connected to Amazon s3.

Can I just drag-n-drop my assets from my local folder over to my s3 folder and keep all relationships for those assets to my elements (entries)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can. Just remember to add your new Assets folder as an assets source to your old Asset fields (fields that are "Asset" types) so users still can add/edit/change their assets.