# What's the best way to move a lot of assets from local to S3 and keep relations

Tags: assets, s3

My client has a catalogue website with a big amount of assets. What's the best way to move the assets from local to Amazon S3?

Comment: See https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9699/can-i-move-a-local-asset-to-s3-and-keep-relations and also https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1212/is-it-possible-to-move-an-entire-asset-source/1215#1215